# How to call EverNote API in Salesforce (Apex)

Tags: apex, api, oauth

I have a requirement for which I need to convert all the opportunities in to ENML and then upload it on EverNote. I have created the ENML. But how can I upload/submit the ENML on evernote?

What is the proper way to upload the ENML, Since there is no official SDK for Apex. I think It can be done via OAuth protocol. Can someone please give me a working example of this in Apex Salesforce since I haven't worked on OAuth protocol before.

Is there a better solution avaialable for the Salesforce integration with EverNote. I am not using business account for EverNote so I can't use the AppExchange application for EverNote.

Comment: you can call the App company support in AppExchange and see if they can provide a trial. something could be achievable with the use of Appexchange if the SFDC API have limitations...

Comment: If you are just dealing with one Evernote account you could bypass OAuth and use the developer token. See http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

Comment: See if you can find the underlying protocol that Evernote uses in http://dev.evernote.com/doc/. It will most likely be SOAP/WSDL, REST/JSON or HTTP based. Then we can figure out how to call it from Apex.

Comment: It is OAuth Protocol I guess. However I have wrote the OAth request methods. Now stuck in signature methods. Don't know whether it should be 'PLAINTEXT' or 'HMAC-SHA1'. Both are not generating the correct header.